# React Native reanimated java.lang.Object.getClass() on a null reference error

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am using the latest version 3.5.1 of react-native-reanimated but this problem seems to persist. I have already included the plugin in babel.config.js

The error says 'Attempt to invoke virtual method java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass() on a null object reference'

I tried reinstalling and using a lower version but didnt work. However, when I use a lower version, it asked me to use the v2 of react-native-reanimated
[Here is a screenshot of the error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx669.jpg)

Comment: try to avoid using images, and write out the actual error instead. It makes it easier for everyOne to search for the exact error messages.